# Another weird Ilustrator bug with transparency mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, cs6

Whenever I create a transparency mask with multiple objects one of them gets automatically moved to the transparency zone. I have no idea why is this happening, it never used to do such thing. I tried ugrouping all objects, but the result is the same. Tried ticking all transparency options and nohing.

Here is a gif to illustrate the problem.

EDIT: Now it's happening when I'm grouping any object. One of them dissapears. What da hell?

[image]

Comment: I suspect the top object is not grouped with the other ones.

Comment: Try grouping the objects you wish to use as a mask.

Comment: I did, and the result was the same too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a "bug".... This is how Illustrator functions and has *always* functioned where Opacity Masks are concerned. A "bug" is an instance of *repeatable* behavior which is unexpected. What you have outlined is entirely *expected* behavior.

Opacity Masks assume the **top object** of a selection should define the mask. It doesn't see "groups" So the top single object or compound shape will define the mask.

Therefore yes, the top most object will become the mask shape. There are a few ways to circumvent that, I've outlined one such method below, but there are others.

If you want that entire shape to be the mask.... make it **one shape** via Pathfinder or create a compound shape. As 3 separate objects, the top object will *always* define the mask.... and Groups don't count.

---

To create a mask containing all 3 of your objects...

- Copy the Objects
- Draw some random shape on top of everything
- Select All
- Click the `Make Mask` button.
- Delete the random shape from the mask
- Paste the previously copied objects on the mask (in front or in back to retain position)